# warning: no such sysroot directory:

Tags: qt, xcode, macos

MacOS Mojave Version 10.14 (18A389).

Обновил Xcode до версии 10.0 (10A255). И теперь, когда я пытаюсь сбилдить мой Qt проект, то получаю ошибку:

```
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from ../greed/timediagram.cpp:1:
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/QtGui:3:
In file included from /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/QtGuiDepends:3:
In file included from /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QtCore:4:
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:202:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:61:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [timediagram.o] Error 1
16:13:47: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта greed (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 clang 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
```

Понятно, что где-то в настройках Qt надо поправить версию, но где? Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение похожей проблемы:
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2107

Попробуйте изменить 2 строки в Darwin-clang-libc++ 
с

```
CC      = $(shell xcrun -find clang)
CXX     = $(shell xcrun -find clang++)
```

на

```
CC      = clang
CXX     = clang++
```

Comment: Да фиг знает. Я переустановил Qt, и всё заработало. На MacOS Mojave очень странные обновления теперь, на предыдущих версиях я видел обновления и Xcode, и Command Line Tool. Теперь только Xcode